# ASP.NET ReportViewer doesn't rotate fonts in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I'm having an issue with how the ASP.NET ReportViewer is rendering my report. The textboxes in the top right corner have a writing mode set to Rotate270 that is not getting picked up in the Chrome version. There appear to be other minor issues as well, but that glaring issue is really my main problem. Is there a setting I can set on the report viewer to help it be more compatible with each browser?

[image: This picture demonstrates my issue in the report rendering]

HTML:

```
    <div class="portlet light bordered">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <span class="h4 caption-subject font-blue-steel bold uppercase">Preview</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <iframe id="reportViewerFrame" style="width: 100%; margin: 0px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="autoResize('reportViewerFrame')"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script that loads preview:

```
   $('.preview-button').on('click', function () {
        var labelID = $('#SelectedFederalLabel').val();
        var labelCount = $('#LabelsToPrint').val();
        var leftMargin = $('#LeftMargin').val();
        var topMargin = $('#TopMargin').val();
        var firstLabelPosition = $('#startOnLabelSliderValue').text();
        var vehicleID = $('#VehicleID').val();

        var url = "../../Reports/LabelViewerHost.aspx?mode=preview" +
            "&vehicleID=" + vehicleID +
            "&labelID=" + labelID +
            "&firstLabelPosition=" + firstLabelPosition +
            "&labelCount=" + labelCount +
            "&leftMargin=" + leftMargin +
            "&topMargin=" + topMargin;

        var reportViewerFrame = document.getElementById('reportViewerFrame');

        if (reportViewerFrame.src) {
            reportViewerFrame.src = url;
        } else if (reportViewerFrame.contentWindow !== null && reportViewerFrame.contentWindow.location !== null) {
            reportViewerFrame.contentWindow.location = url;
        } else {
            reportViewerFrame.setAttribute('src', url);
        }

        $(".preview-section").slideDown();
    });
```

LabelViewerHost.aspx.cs Page_Load Event (C#):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }

    _queryParameters =
        HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(
            HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString());

    string mode = _queryParameters.Get("mode");

    ReportGenerationMode reportGenerationMode =
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mode) || mode == "preview") ?
        ReportGenerationMode.Preview :
        ReportGenerationMode.Print;

    ...
    Parse Query Parameters
    ...

    try
    {
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer reportViewer =
            reportGenerationMode == ReportGenerationMode.Preview ?
            PreviewReportViewer :
            new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();

        reportViewer.Reset();
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(_federalLabel.ReportFile);

        #region Set report parameters

        reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("LabelsToPrint", _labelCount.ToString()));
        ... // I do this more

        #endregion Set report parameters

        reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO
    }       
}
```